# Can you edit the quality of user uploaded images on Cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I have a website where users upload images.

I would like the quality of all the already uploaded images + any newly uploaded images to be the same.

Is there a way to easily edit the already uploaded images without having to get users to re-upload their respective images?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beautiful of Cloudinary is to be able to upload the originals and then apply a transformation. Typically the recommendation looks to be:

1. Set `quality` parameter as `auto` (**q_auto** in URLs) to automatically adjust the quality of the image for the right balance between quality and size
2. Set `fetch_format` parameter as `auto` (**f_auto** in URLs) to automatically choose the best format depending on the browser.
3. Adjusting the height and width to necessary dimensions being rendered on the page.

Example: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/q_auto,f_auto,w_500/bike.jpg

**Source (and more info)**: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_optimization).

But if you need to re-upload the content and keep the same `public_id`, the easiest solution would be to use their APIs. I would suggest doing the following:

1. Retrieve the assets that need to be re-uploaded using the [Admin APIs get resources call](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources). I would suggest breaking these down by `resource_type` and I would also include the parameters `tags` set as `true` and `context` set as `true` if being used. **Note** The Admin API is rate limited so check what usage limit is associated to your plan [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#usage_limits). Store these in an array for use later. The response should include `public_id`, `url`, `tags`, `context`, etc...
2. Iterate over the previous array and use the [Upload API's upload method](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) to re-upload the content using the same parameters retrieved earlier (`public_id`, `url`, `tags`, `context`, etc.. e.g.

   ```
   current_assets = [...]
   for (asset in current_assets) {
       result = cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
           asset['url'], 
           { public_id: asset['public_id'], tags: asset['tags'], context: assets['context']
           // include any incoming transformations to apply to the asset during upload
           },
           (err, res) => {
               if (err) console.log(err);
           console.log(res);
       })
   }
   ```

**Source**: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images?query=incoming&c_query=Incoming%20transformations#incoming_transformations